# menu bar icons not shown Eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse, select, menu, menubar

The menu bar is shown but my icons does not show at the top of my layout.

Menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_write"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/action_write"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_read"
      android:title="@string/action_read"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Display Menu:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I am using 4.4.2 on Galaxy Note 3. I tried so many things but nothing work (6 hrs). I am using appcompat_v7.

Extend:

```
public class myActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try android:showAsAction="always".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_write"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/action_write"
      yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_read"
      android:title="@string/action_read"
      yourapp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Example from Android developer website:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

> Using XML attributes from the support library Notice that the
>   showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the
>    tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by
>   the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the
>   Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace
>   as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Oh so if my app was called "helloword" I would have to declare `xmlns:helloworld="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >`  and `helloword:showAsAction="ifRoom"` ?

Comment: I personally will just call it "xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", then "app:showAsAction", but after I read the developer guide, I guess you could probably use your own namespace too.

Comment: I tried this with appcompat v7 support from the Eclipse extra and it did not work (telling me to use " android: "instead) but I just changed to appcompat v7. Maybe it will work, thanks for the reply. Will try when im up.

Comment: I notice you were 22 yesterday and now 23, so happy birthday :D

Comment: Wow!you are stalker! Haha! Thank you.